# openni tracker not producing any output

Tags: kinect, openni, openi-tracker, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the openni_tracker node to duplicate the results from the wiki
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker  although the openni_tracker node just isn't producing any output.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/6UwjxvzX) is a log from running openni_tracker (openni_tracker.xml set to log info-level messages to screen.)  It looks like openni_tracker is detecting users, but it is not publishing any data or displaying any images.  rostopic -list just returns /rosout and /rossout_agg.

I have visualized Kinect point cloud data in rviz with openni_launch, so I doubt that this is a hardware problem.  Does anyone have ideas on why openni_tracker is not publishing any data?  I'd really appreciate any help in figuring this out!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12866/openni-tracker-not-producing-any-output/) by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2012-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Starting openni.launch in the openni package should be responsible for creating the links between the kinect and your map/fixed frame (maybe you have to ajjust the tf-frames to your scenario). To track the human, you should additionally start the openni_tracker. It should output if a User is detected and instructions about the calibration step (to calibrate the tracker, the user has to do the Phi-pose). As soon as the calibration was successful, the skelleton joints are posted on tf... (Very often, calibration fails, in this case, don´t worry, just do the Phi-pose again..)

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-11**:
FYI for anyone reading, the Psi pose doesn't appear to be necessary. (Maybe this was once the case but is no longer). It should pick you up immediately.

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-11**:
What this answer doesn't mention is that to visualize in RViz you need to select /openni_depth_frame as your Fixed Frame.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Openni tracker usually publishes the joints of the human skelleton on the TF topic. Therefore your TF configuration should be correct, i.e. links between your fixed-frame and your kinect-frame have to exist. Did you check if transforms are beeing sent on topic /tf ?

You can also visualize tf in rviz and check the warnings if and what transforms are missing...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-02-02**:
see entry below...

**Comment by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) on 2012-02-02**:
With just openni_tracker, nothing is published, the topic /tf does not exist..  If I additionally launch openni.launch, several transforms are published (camera_link, camera_rgb_frame, etc.) but still nothing from openni_tracker.  What is the minimum config for seeing skeleton data?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the help michikarg.  My problem was that openni_tracker required the param "camera_frame_id" identifying the transform from world coordinates to the kinect.  I used the following [launch file](http://pastebin.com/NuJEYaf0) to set "camera_frame_id" to /camera_link which is published by openni_launch.

Now, sequentially running
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
roslaunch my_pkg the_above_launch_file
successfully results in all of the transforms being published!

---

Originally posted by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) with karma: 145 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ideally you should not be required to run any node or launch file to get openni tracker started. ROS openni tracker is a stand alone node. As far as /tf topics are concerned they will only be published once the node has started tracking the user. You can monitor the console output of the program and when it says 'started tracking user #' then /tf topics will be published.

No change is required in 'camera_frame_id' , keep it to 'openni_depth_frame' and while visualizing in rviz keep your fixed/reference frame to 'openni_depth_frame'.

Just in case you want to visualize the pointcloud/depth/rgb images along with /tf skeleton tree , just change the 'camera_frame_id'

string frame_id("openni_depth_frame");

pnh.getParam("camera_frame_id", frame_id);

to

string frame_id("openni_rgb_optical_frame"); // what ever you want here

pnh.getParam("camera_frame_id", frame_id);

Hope it helps, you might want to checkout my posts about other issues while get these things running [http://tayyabnaseer.blogspot.de/2012/04/running-ros-openni-tracker-with.html]   :-)

---

Originally posted by [tayyab](https://answers.ros.org/users/2123/tayyab/) with karma: 59 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-11**:
Thanks for making it clear that you do NOT need to run openni.launch to use the tracker! However, your method of linking the frame to an existing tf tree is bad and unnecessary. You can specify "camera_frame_id" on the Parameter Server. You should not be editing and recompiling the source code!